# Errors while binding a .jar/.aar file for Xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am currently trying to bind a .jar file to a C# project for Xamarin.android. the [Troubleshooting](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/) section on bindings suggests that I look into the .jar file.

One of the errors I get is:
CS0234 : The type or namespace name 'CommonUsbSerialPort' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Caen.VCPSerialPort.Driver' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The class exists but is not bound (I checked with JD-GUI).
My Question is: what do I have to do next, now that I know that the class exists and the auto binding does not work?

I also get a lot of CS0115 error. For example:
'CAENRFIDCdcAcmSerialDriver.CdcAcmSerialPort.ThresholdClass': no suitable method found to override

Thanks in advance.
Ben